# Adicionar valores a un arreglo que esta dentro de otro arreglo

Tags: javascript, array

Colegas, estoy intentando adicionar elementos dentro de un arreglo que se encuentra dentro de otro arreglo. El objetivo de esto es para asignar colores aleatorios con una función que implemente a un gráfico. La función de asignar colores la probé y me funciona perfecto, pero a la hora de asignar colores dentro del arreglo no me asigan ninguna color:

Esta es la función de asignar colores de forma aleatoria:

```
function dame_color_aleatorio(){
        hexadecimal = new Array("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A","B","C","D","E","F");
        color_aleatorio = "#";
        for (i=0;i<6;i++){
            posarray = aleatorio(0,hexadecimal.length);
            color_aleatorio += hexadecimal[posarray];
        }
        return color_aleatorio;
    }

    function aleatorio(inferior,superior){
        numPosibilidades = superior - inferior;
        aleat = Math.random() * numPosibilidades;
        aleat = Math.floor(aleat);
        return parseInt(inferior) + aleat;
    }
```

Esta es la función donde intento asignar los colores dentro del arreglo:

```
var data = {
        labels: [
            "Symbian",
            "Blackberry",
            "Other",
            "Android",
            "IOS"
        ],
        datasets: [{
            data: JSON.parse("{!! toJsJson( valoresEspecialistaVistaHome() ) !!}"),
            backgroundColor: [
                
            ]
            /*hoverBackgroundColor: [
                "#CFD4D8",
                "#B370CF",
                "#34495E",
                "#36CAAB",
                "#49A9EA"
            ]*/

        }]
    };

    for (i=0;i<5;i++){
        data.datasets.backgroundColor.push(dame_color_aleatorio());
    }

        var canvasDoughnut = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas1"), {
            type: 'doughnut',
            tooltipFillColor: "rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.55)",
            data: data
        });
```

Como puedo resolver este problema. sldos

Answer (score 1):

Lo que ocurre es que `data.datasets` es un arreglo por lo que `data.datasets.backgroundColor` devuelve `undefined`. Tal como tienes definido el objeto `data` el código del `for` debe quedarte así:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    data.datasets[0].backgroundColor.push(dame_color_aleatorio());
}
```